# Why doesn't X11 forwarding work for me on MacOS?

Tags: mac, docker, x11-forwarding

I am following [this](https://cntnr.io/running-guis-with-docker-on-mac-os-x-a14df6a76efc) tutorial to run GUI from docker on a MacOS host.

```
brew install socat
brew install xquartz
```

and then using `open -a Xquartz` I enable connections from clients:

[image]

Then I run `socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"` and from a different shell I run:

```
docker run -e DISPLAY=192.168.0.235:0 --privileged jess/chrome
```

But I get:

```
(google-chrome:1): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 192.168.0.235:0
```

Where `192.168.0.235` is the ip I see at `en0` inet's entry.

Seems my firewall is ok too, maybe something with the network I am using?

[image]

Comment: What's your firewall situation? For example, if you're running macOS's built-in application firewall, have you configured it to allow Xquartz to receive incoming connections? See: System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > [Click padlock to unlock] > Firewall Options…

Comment: @Spiff it looks ok I guess. see the edit above.

Answer (score 3):

When you install `xquartz` you need to logout and login again in order for it to come in affect.

Because you installed from `homebrew` you may not have seen the dialog box.